# 'Run As Different Users' behaves differently with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, terminal, runas

I'm using "Run As Different User" when running a PowerShell script, and it is behaving differently than when I run the script in a normal PowerShell Terminal.  For example, if I try to run the following code in the "Run As" terminal, it runs into an error.  But if I run it with a normal terminal it works just fine.

```
function Replace-Word(
    [string]$Document,
    [string]$FindText,
    [string]$ReplaceText
  )
{
    $ReplaceAll = 2
    $FindContinue = 1

    $MatchCase = $False
    $MatchWholeWord = $True 
    $MatchWildcards = $False 
    $MatchSoundsLike = $False 
    $MatchAllWordForms = $False
    $Forward = $True
    $Wrap = $FindContinue
    $Format = $False

    $Word = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
    $Word.Visible = $False

    $OpenDoc = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
    $Selection = $Word.Selection

    $Selection.Find.Execute(
    $FindText,
    $MatchCase,
    $MatchWholeWord,
    $MatchWildcards,
    $MatchSoundsLike,
    $MatchAllWordForms,
    $Forward,
    $Wrap,
    $Format,
    $ReplaceText,
    $ReplaceAll
    ) | Out-Null

    $OpenDoc.Close()
    $Word.quit()
}


Copy-Item "C:\Welcome.DOC" "C:\test.DOC"

Replace-Word -Document "C:\test.DOC" -FindText '<UserName>' -ReplaceText "JohnDoe"
Replace-Word -Document "C:\test.DOC" -FindText '<EmailAddress>' -ReplaceText "JohnDoe@example.com"
```

The errors I get when running as a different user are:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\lbradstr\Desktop\TechRepo\NewEEsetup\NewUserSetup.ps1:2668 char:9
+         $Selection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\lbradstr\Desktop\TechRepo\NewEEsetup\NewUserSetup.ps1:2670 char:9
+         $OpenDoc.Close()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\lbradstr\Desktop\TechRepo\NewEEsetup\NewUserSetup.ps1:2668 char:9
+         $Selection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\lbradstr\Desktop\TechRepo\NewEEsetup\NewUserSetup.ps1:2670 char:9
+         $OpenDoc.Close()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Both terminals are running the same version of PowerShell:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14409  1012
```

I would run this code in a normal terminal if I could, but this is only part of a larger script I am running.  The rest of the script needs administrative privileges to run, which is why I use the "Run As" feature.  Any ideas about why the code would execute differently between the two user accounts? Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: The errors suggest that while creating the `$Word` object itself succeeded, opening the document `$OpenDoc = ...` failed. Are you passing relative paths? Is the working directory the same in both sessions?

Comment: typically, the problem is permissions. does the selected account have permission to reach that file? ///// also, is $Selection = $Word.Selection correct? it LOOKS like it otta be $Selection = $OpenDoc.Selection, but i can't test that since i use LibreOffice

Comment: How do you run it under diff user? Runas /noprofile .... If so, remove /noprofile, I think office apps requires profile to be loaded

Comment: Has the other account logged into the machine and launched Word? Are we sure that when you create the ComObject it isn't just quietly stuck at a screen that is saying 'Welcome to MS Word', or is trying to validate a license or something? Try changing `$Word.Visible = $False` to `$Word.Visible = $True` and add a `Start-Sleep -Sec 15` after it so you can see the state of the application when run under the other user's context.

Comment: @mklement0 I am using an absolute path to a shared drive on a separate computer. I checked and can access the file from both profiles.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I do have permission to access the document for both profiles.  Also, I'll look into $Selection = $Word.Selection.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeTwc Hi Mike, I run as a different user by doing Ctrl-Shift-right click on the PowerShell icon, then I can select 'Run As Different User' and put in my administrative creds.  Thanks!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, I did what you suggested and it worked! After trying it with a 15 second pause, I tried just 5 and changed $word.visible back to $false.  That worked great too. I guess it needed some extra time to open the file.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @leah_cyberpadawan - glad to know you got it fixed ... and that is _was_ an access problem, just not a permissions access problem. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Everyone else's suggestion still apply (once permissions and ACL to the file has been sorted) and it is still giving you this error... THEN:

This is a classic case of locked file in Word. You need to release the COM Object from your last PowerShell session because it is probably still accessing the file and causing issues.

Once you release the COM Object or close all word processes, try running as again and it should work.